# How can I change wordpress theme related posts other to random?

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I make the related posts shown in the bottom of the post be random posts from that category/tag? Right now it shows the latest posts from that categories/tags but I would like to show random posts. Any idea how I can do that?
 I found this in my theme's functions.php .
I'm a newbie so please explain it as easy as possible.

Thanks a lot!

```
/**
 * Related Posts
 *
 * @since 1.0
 */
function dp_related_posts($args = '') {
    global $post;

    $query_args = array();

    $defaults = array(
        'view' => 'grid-mini',
        'number' => 0,
        'fields' => '' // object, html or leave it blank
    );
    $args = wp_parse_args($args, $defaults);
    extract($args);

    // Only displayed on singular post pages
    if(!is_singular())
        return;

    // Check limited number
    if(!$number)
        return;

    // Check taxonomies
    $taxes = get_post_taxonomies($post->ID);

    if(empty($taxes))
        return;

    $taxes = array_unique(array_merge(array('post_tag', 'category'), $taxes));

    $tax_query = array();
    $in_tax_query_array = array();
    $and_tax_query_array = array();

    foreach($taxes as $tax) {
        if($tax == 'post_format') {
            // Post format
            $post_format = get_post_format($post->ID);
            if(!$post_format) $post_format = 'standard';
            $post_format_query_array = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'post-format-'.$post_format,
                'operator' => 'IN'
            );

            continue;
        }

        $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, $tax);

        if(empty($terms))
            continue;
        $term_ids = array();
        foreach($terms as $term)
            $term_ids[] = $term->term_id;

        $in_tax_query_array[$tax] = array(
            'taxonomy' => $tax,
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $term_ids,
            'operator' => 'IN'
        );

        $and_tax_query_array[$tax] = array(
            'taxonomy' => $tax,
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $term_ids,
            'operator' => 'AND'
        );
    }

    if(empty($in_tax_query_array) && empty($and_tax_query_array))
        return;     

    $query_args = array(
        'post_type' => get_post_type($post->ID),
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => true, 
        'posts_per_page' => $number
    );

    $current_post_id = $post->ID;
    $found_posts = array();

    // Multiple Taxonomy Query: relation = AND, operator = AND
    $query_args['tax_query'] = $and_tax_query_array;
    $query_args['tax_query'][] = $post_format_query_array;
    $query_args['tax_query']['relation'] = 'AND';
    $query_args['post__not_in'] = array($post->ID);
    $related = new WP_Query($query_args); 
    foreach($related->posts as $post)
        $found_posts[] = $post->ID;

    // Multiple Taxonomy Query: relation = AND, operator = IN
    if(count($found_posts) < $number) {
        $query_args['tax_query'] = $in_tax_query_array;
        $query_args['tax_query'][] = $post_format_query_array;
        $query_args['tax_query']['relation'] = 'AND';
        $query_args['post__not_in'] = array_merge(array($current_post_id), $found_posts);
        $related = new WP_Query($query_args); 
        foreach($related->posts as $post)
            $found_posts[] = $post->ID;
    }

    $post_format_query = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => get_post_format(),
        'operator' => 'IN'
    );

    // Foreach Each Taxonomy Query: operator = AND
    if(count($found_posts) < $number) {

        foreach($and_tax_query_array as $and_tax_query) {
            $query_args['tax_query'] = array($and_tax_query);
            $query_args['tax_query'][] = $post_format_query_array;
            $query_args['tax_query']['relation'] = 'AND';
            $query_args['post__not_in'] = array_merge(array($current_post_id), $found_posts);
            $related = new WP_Query($query_args);
            foreach($related->posts as $post)
                $found_posts[] = $post->ID;

            if(count($found_posts) > $number)
                break;
        }
    }

    // Foreach Each Taxonomy Query: operator = IN
    if(count($found_posts) < $number) {

        foreach($in_tax_query_array as $in_tax_query) {
            $query_args['tax_query'] = array($in_tax_query);
            $query_args['tax_query'][] = $post_format_query_array;
            $query_args['tax_query']['relation'] = 'AND';
            $query_args['post__not_in'] = array_merge(array($current_post_id), $found_posts);
            $related = new WP_Query($query_args);
            foreach($related->posts as $post)
                $found_posts[] = $post->ID;

            if(count($found_posts) > $number)
                break;
        }
    }

    if(empty($found_posts))
        return;

    $query_args['tax_query'] = '';
    $query_args['post__in'] = $found_posts;
    $related = new WP_Query($query_args);

    if($fields == 'object')
        return $related;

    if(!empty($args['template']) && is_callable($args['template'])) {
        call_user_func($args['template'], $related);
        return;
    }
    ?>

    <div class="section-box related-posts">
        <div class="section-header"><h3 class="section-title"><?php _e('You may also like', 'dp') ?></h3></div>

        <div class="section-content <?php echo $view; ?>"><div class="nag cf">
            <?php if( $related->have_posts() ) : while( $related->have_posts() ) : $related->the_post(); 
            global $post;
            global $section_view;
            $section_view = 'grid-mini';
            get_template_part('item-video');
            endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
        </div></div>
    </div><!-- end .related-posts -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the argument 'orderby' => 'rand' I think should do it. 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Comment: I tried to add it but it isn't doing anything. Probably I added it in the wrong place... Can you tell me where to add it in the code above? Please

Comment: I'm thinking you would add it like this: $query_args['orderby'] = 'rand';                  Just before your line: $related = new WP_Query($query_args);

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to upvote the answer too so I get all those sweet, sweet Internet points ;)

Answer (score 0):

With this code:

```
<div class="relatedposts">
    <h3>Random related articles</h3>
    <?php
    $related = get_posts( array( 'category__in' => wp_get_post_categories($post->ID), 'orderby' => 'rand' , 'numberposts' => 3, 'post__not_in' => array($post->ID) ) );
    if( $related ) foreach( $related as $post ) {
    setup_postdata($post); ?>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(243,150)); ?></a>

    <?php }
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
                    ?>
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: Well is not include inquirer question but tell you to know, this code says get 3 related posts of the current post by the same category and random then show their thumbnails by sizes 243px X 150px and link it to their permalink. And also no need any `functions.php` codes as other solutions.